# Boilerplate for Apache Cordova with Crosswalk

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, crosswalk-runtime

I see that Apache Cordova got a big update mid-April 2015, this includes moving to npm (including the plugin modules), plus support for Crosswalk.

I'm looking at creating a rapid prototype app that will work on Android and iOS devices.

I wondered if anyone knows of a decent / up-to-date boilerplate for Cordova with crosswalk, bootstrap and jQuery?

Cheers,
Ollie